# how to get only some of the strings in a list while using random,shuffle? in python

Tags: python, random, dictionary, shuffle

When creating a dictionary from a list, i use

```
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(list)
    print "".join(list)
```

that way i get 10 different random combinations of the list, but if the list has 10 strings, each random i get will have 10 strings, like so:

```
>>> list
['1', 'n', 'f', 'g', 'z', 'j', '5', 's', '2', '3']
>>> for i in range(5):
...    random.shuffle(list)
...    print "".join(list)
... 
13jgzs25nf
15zngs2jf3
jgfsn3z251
g3sf512zjn
5nsj3fg21z
```

however, i only want random combinations compiled from, lets say, only 5 out of the 10 strings in the list, how do i go about doing that?

ty!

==========================

```
@volatility
in an attempt to use what you showed me but try to get a full list like i did in my question i did this:

>>> lst=["1","2","3","f","s","g","5","n","z","j"]
>>> for i in range(10):
...     random.sample(list, 3)
...     print "".join(list)
... 
['5', '2', 'n']
gj5nfs231z
['n', '5', '1']
gj5nfs231z
['z', '3', 'j']
gj5nfs231z
['5', 'g', 'n']
gj5nfs231z
['g', 'z', '2']
gj5nfs231z
['2', '3', 'f']
gj5nfs231z
['g', '2', '5']
gj5nfs231z
['3', 'n', '2']
gj5nfs231z
['g', 'z', '2']
gj5nfs231z
['n', 's', 'g']
gj5nfs231z
```

which is progress i guess? what i would ultimately like to get would be an input that looks like this (if i used the above list)

```
52n
z3j
5gn
23f
g25
3n2
gz2
nsg
```

is that doable?

Comment: You've mixed Volatility's function with falsetru's call pattern, which won't work because `sample` isn't in-place but `shuffle` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) for that:

```
>>> lst = ['1', 'n', 'f', 'g', 'z', 'j', '5', 's', '2', '3']
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(lst, 5)
['f', 's', '3', 'z', 'n']
```

To get the output you want, you can simply put it inside a `for` loop:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...    print ''.join(random.sample(lst, 5))
...
jn513
13g2f
nfsj5
nj3s1
3zn51
sgj2f
5ns3g
sg51z
23j1z
n2g53
```

---

Side note: don't use `list` as a variable name - it shadows the built-in `list` type.

Comment: thank you that progresses me a-bit. though the output im looking for would be a clean one (which is why i use "".join) but with more than one option. so ill get an input that looks like the one in my question but each string will be shorter

Comment: you are THE MAN! thank you so much for taking the time to show me this.. it will help me ALOT!

Comment: @Giladiald no worries :)

Answer (score 4):

Use slice notation.

```
>>> lst = ['1', 'n', 'f', 'g', 'z', 'j', '5', 's', '2', '3']
>>> random.shuffle(lst)
>>> lst[:5]
['n', 'j', 's', 'z', 'f']
>>> ''.join(lst[:5])
'njszf'
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

---

```
>>> lst = ['1', 'n', 'f', 'g', 'z', 'j', '5', 's', '2', '3']
>>> for i in range(10):
...     random.shuffle(lst)
...     print ''.join(lst[:5])
...
s3f52
f351s
gnz5j
g2s5n
g3n51
g2fsj
532jf
3f1ng
jnfg5
z35sn
```

Comment: ok so how do i use this but make it show me 10 or 20 possible combinations and not just one?